# Set TabBarIcons when application is launching

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

What I want to do seems pretty easy but I do not get it work.
I have a tabbarview controller as rootview controller including 4 tab bars. I want to set the tab bar icons within the app delegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

So my question is, how do I get access to my tabbars within the app delegate?

I want to set the tabbar icons programmatically cause I want to use the xcode system icons.

Comment: What kind of Xcode icons do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use the favorite icon.

Comment: You can do that in storyboards too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think xcode provides you a set on icons to use on tab bars. The SDK provides you some system things like buttons, or bar buttons. How ever To change the tabs icons with your own icons just set your tabBar on your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method like this:

```
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,viewController4, nil];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Then in each view of you tabBar you do something like this

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabIcon"];
    }
    return self;
}
```